# JavaScript: How to access an array object inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am struggling to access an array object inside of an object in JavaScript. Here is the overall object structure.

```
categories: Array(5)
0:
name: "Electronics"
subCategories: Array(16)
0:
name: "Video Games & Accessories"
__typename: "SubCategory"
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {__typename: 'SubCategory', name: 'UPS & Surge Protection'}
2: {__typename: 'SubCategory', name: 'Tablets'}
```

Here is my react code for fetching the object.

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const CATEGORY = gql`
  {
    categories {
      name
      subCategories {
        name
      }
    }
  }
`;
const Hero = () => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(CATEGORY);
  return (
    <div>
      
      <div className="flex space-x-16 p-4 mt-10">
        <div className=" w-64  bg-green-500">
          {data?.categories?.subCategories?.map((launch) => (
            <div key={launch.id}>{launch.name}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="flex-1  bg-green-500">dgfd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

I wanted to map `subCategory` `name` dynamically. What is my mistake on here?

```
<div className="flex space-x-16 p-4 mt-10">
            <div className=" w-64  bg-green-500">
              {data?.categories?.subCategories?.map((launch) => (
                <div key={launch.id}>{launch.name}</div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

Here is the `json` data

```
{
  "categories": [
    {
      "__typename": "Category",
      "name": "Electronics",
      "subCategories": [
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Video Games & Accessories"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "UPS & Surge Protection"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Tablets"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "TV's"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Software"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Routers, Servers & Networking"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Projectors"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Printers, Scanners & Copiers"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Other Electronics"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Mobile Phones"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Mobile Accessories"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Laptops"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Digital Cameras"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Desktop Computers"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Computer Accessories"
        },
        {
          "__typename": "SubCategory",
          "name": "Audio & Video Equipment"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Thanks

Comment: The subcategories don't seem to have an `id` property, you're trying to use it for the `key` prop on a div.

Comment: @timotgl it's for key only? can you spot my mistake there? Thanks

Comment: That was the only issue i could spot. You can try to print your data object with `JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)` and paste that here with proper indentation, the text you copied from the console (I'm assuming) is hard to read.

Comment: @timotgl I just minimize the object structure, take a look at it now. Thanks

Comment: Everything looks correct. What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: I got `undefined' error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243544/discussion-between-timotgl-and-tesh-aych).

Comment: Are you updating the state or reloading the component structure after the data is loaded? it doesn't seem so from the code. You are not using the loading part either, perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: @AdityaRastogi what can I do? please show me how to use loading if that's the error? Thanks

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#usequery
Try referring to this, could you also check if the request is correctly fetching the data?

Comment: @AdityaRastogi Yes, it gives me the `categories` name but i can't get `subCategories` name, what is the issue?

Comment: Could you post the data json?

Comment: @AdityaRastogi I just posted the data json, Look at it. It doesn't return `subCategories` name

Comment: Categories is an array so try categories[0].subcategories.map

Comment: all js arrays are objects and hence have a corresponding name property, but categories itself will not have a subcategories property, each category will have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243547/discussion-between-aditya-rastogi-and-tesh-aych).

Comment: That's the correct answer. It works now. Thanks, Appreciate it

Comment: I'll make an answer then for users that might come to this question later

Comment: @TeshAych could you mark the answer or suggest edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subcategories are not being accessed as they are inside an array inside categories and won't be accessed directly.
Accessing it as categories[0].subcategories or any other valid index should do the job